# Device rooting fails, but doesn't brick?

Tags: rooting

I've was trying to root my Vodafone 858 Smart (Froyo) using super one click but it stopped in the middle of the operation and the program was non-responsive so I closed and it was closed while installing super user and it couldn't install it due to low phone memory.

So I tried rooting it again after clearing some phone memory it roots but I don't have super user or busy box but I can access super user capabilities from adb so how can I root my phone properly?

Comment: You should be able to install super user from the market https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.noshufou.android.su&feature=nav_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDMsImNvbS5ub3NodWZvdS5hbmRyb2lkLnN1Il0. Busy box... I know  you can download it via TitaniumBackup, I can't remember where else.

Comment: @Bryan  thank you it worked with the super user but i just wanna know what does busy box do?

Comment: I don't know *exactly* what all it contains, but it has tools, etc. for developers to use that are beneficial to them in their root apps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install Busybox from the market too: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=stericson.busybox&hl=en

And to your other question

> i just wanna know what does busy box do?

taken from market description:

BusyBox is a software application that provides many standard Unix tools, much like the larger (but more capable) GNU Core Utilities. BusyBox is designed to be a small executable for use with the Linux kernel, which makes it ideal for use with embedded devices. It has been self-dubbed "The Swiss Army Knife of Embedded Linux".

[The official BusyBox website about page](http://busybox.net/about.html) has some more info about what it is too.